# Failed to load API definition

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo, en la actualidad estamos desarrollando un `web API` para tener la información disponible de una base de datos y luego suministrársela al cliente del API para presentarla en un sitio web.

Dentro de la solución diseñada para el `web API`, manejo dos proyectos, un proyecto para modelar la base de datos el cual catalogo como `AnalistaFlotasDAL` y un proyecto donde se crea el API denominado `AnalistaFlotasWAPIL`. En el proyecto `AnalistaFlotasWAPIL` tengo un controlador que me esta generando un error al momento de hacer la ejecución de manera local. Cuando ejecuto, soy dirigido a la URL https://localhost:7166/swagger/index.html. Allí me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
Failed to load API definition.
Errors
 
Fetch error
response status is 500 https://localhost:7166/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

Luego de esto, voy a la URL indicada para ver mas detalles del error, la cual es: https://localhost:7166/swagger/v1/swagger.json. Allí podemos obtener la siguiente información:

```
SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - AnalistaFlotasWAPIL.Controllers.JornadasController.FuntionJornadaEstado (AnalistaFlotasWAPIL). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerDocumentWithoutFilters(string documentName, string host, string basePath)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerAsync(string documentName, string host, string basePath)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Al ver esto pude notar que hay un problema con la función FuntionJornadaEstado que utilizo en un método dentro de esta misma clase. La función es la siguiente:

```
public string? FuntionJornadaEstado(string? estado_autorizacion)
    {
        if (estado_autorizacion is null)
        {
            return "pendiente";
        }
        else if (estado_autorizacion == "autorizada")
        {
            return "autorizada";
        }
        else
        {
            return "rechazada";
        }
    }
```

Esta función la utilizo en este método:

```
[HttpGet("/Jornadas/Tabla/Estado/Todos", Name = "GetJornadasTablaEstadoTodos")]
    public List<TemGeneJornadaDiariaAutorizacionPendienteView> GetJornadasTablaEstadoTodos(int Ano,
        int Mes, int Dia, string? Obra, string? Nombre, string? Equipo)
    {
        var q6 = from a in context.CalcGeneJornadaDiaria
                 where (Ano == 0 || Ano == a.fecha_informe.Year)
                 && (Mes == 0 || Mes == a.fecha_informe.Month)
                 && (Dia == 0 || Dia == a.fecha_informe.Day)
                 && (Obra == null || Obra == "" || Obra == a.descripcioncentro)
                 && (Nombre == null || Nombre == "" || Nombre == a.nombre_completo)
                 && (Equipo == null || Equipo == "" || Equipo == a.equipo)
                 select new TemGeneJornadaDiariaAutorizacionPendiente
                 {
                     registro = a.registro,
                     fecha = a.fecha_informe,
                     Operario = a.cedula,
                     nombre = a.nombre_completo,
                     cargo = a.descripcioncargo,
                     centro = a.centro,
                     descripcioncentro = a.descripcioncentro,
                     descripcionnomina = a.descripcionnomina,
                     Hora_Inicio = a.Hora_Inicio,
                     Hora_Fin = a.Hora_Fin,
                     Inicio_Receso = a.Inicio_Receso,
                     Fin_Receso = a.Fin_Receso,
                     Laboro = a.Laboro,
                     Destino = a.Destino,
                     tipo = a.TipoJornada,
                     equipo = a.equipo,
                     Orden_Taller = a.Orden_Taller,
                     Codigo_Operacion = a.Codigo_Operacion,
                     Componente = a.Componente,
                     descripcion_labor = a.descripcion_labor,
                     incidente = a.incidente,
                     Riesgos = a.Riesgos,
                     usuario = a.UsuarioRegistro,
                     fecha_registro = a.fecha_registro,
                     //Aqui se debe poner una funcion que defina el estado de la autorizacion
                     estado_autorizacion = FuntionJornadaEstado(a.estado_autorizacion)
                 };

        //2023-08-30: con el animo de ponerle un dato unico a las filas de datos, tomo el campo registro y lo 
        //modifico con un for, asi ese dato sera unico en las ejecuciones.
        var q7 = q6.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < q7.Count; i++)
        {
            q7[i].registro = i;
        }
        return q7.Select(j => new TemGeneJornadaDiariaAutorizacionPendienteView(j)).ToList();
    }
```

Aparentemente es como si no pudiera utilizar la función dentro de esta clase, la cual es un controller. Atentos a sus indicaciones.

Comment: Cuando swagger tira un error asi, quiere decir que tu controller tiene mas de un endpoint que apunta al mismo lugar.. que fue lo ultimo que agregaste??? si no, lo que podes hacer es borrar todo, ir agregnado de a uno a ver cual fallo...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, dentro del controller, lo ultimo que agregue fue la función FuntionJornadaEstado. Si comento la función y el lugar donde la invoco, se corrige el error y funciona el web Api. La duda que me surge, es donde debo crear la funcion para luego invocarla en el controller.

Comment: Te falta la anotacion para que swagger sepa que tipo de endpoint es... o vos querias que fuera privada? si es publica, tenes que acararle si es un get o post o de que tipo es...

Comment: En realidad creo que no es un endpoint, no??? entonces deberia ser privada, si nadie mas la va a usar y sobre todo si esta en el controller... capaz, deberia estar o en un helper o en una clase que sea llamada por el endpoint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradecemos gbianchi por sus comentarios que fueron de gran ayuda.
La situación la resolvimos modificando el ámbito de la función FuntionJornadaEstado de public a privado. De esa forma el EndPoint  GetJornadasTablaEstadoTodos puede consumir la función. La función corregida quedo así:

```
private string? FuntionJornadaEstado(string? estado_autorizacion)
{
    if (estado_autorizacion is null)
    {
        return "pendiente";
    }
    else if (estado_autorizacion == "autorizada")
    {
        return "autorizada";
    }
    else
    {
        return "rechazada";
    }
}
```